# Error while doing insert/update in MySql

Tags: mysql

I want to capture the error occurring during inserting or updating data in mysql Stored procedures.

When a data is updated in DB, no of rows modified can be checked to know whether update or insert happened successfully or not, but even if rows affected is 0 (same data updated again), it may not be an error condition.

i want to capture only insert/update is failed.
Please share some light on the same

My Sp is something like below

```
DELIMITER $$

    CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_test`(
            IN param1 VARCHAR(50), 
            IN param2 VARCHAR(50)
        )
        BEGIN
            IF updateCount > 0 THEN
                UPDATE tbname SET val = param1 where con = param2;
            ELSE
                INSERT INTO tbname SET val = param1,con = param2;
            END IF;

        END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

I want to track whether the statements has executed successfully or not.

Answer (score -1):

I have added an exception block like below,

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
BEGIN
    GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 @sqlstate = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, 
    @errno = MYSQL_ERRNO, @text = MESSAGE_TEXT;
    SET @full_error = CONCAT("ERROR ", @errno, " (", @sqlstate, "): ", @text);
    SELECT @full_error;
END;
```

No I am getting the errors. I think this would be fine for my scenario. If any one find a better answer please post here.

Comment: Add that in to your question, its not an answer.

Comment: What does *"No I am getting the errors"* mean? Does it mean *"No, I am getting the errors"* or *"Now I am getting the errors"* or *"No I am not getting the errors"*?